# Excelファイルの走査にかかる時間を改善したい

Tags: python

#### 目的

あるexcelファイルにおいて特定の文字列を含むセルの情報（行，列情報）が欲しいです。
走査方法は100列を行ごとに走査し，それを100行分繰り返します。
走査部分のコードは次のとおりです。
（worksheetはactiveにしていること前提です。またopenpyxlライブラリを使用しています。）

```
for r in range(1, 100):
     for c in range(1, 100):
            if ws.cell(row=r, column=c).value != None:
                if "パソコン" in ws.cell(row=r, column=c).value:
            #search_cells.append(ws.cell(row=r, column=c).value)
                    print(r,c)
```

正しい出力結果は得られましたが，もっと簡単で速度の速い取得方法はありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`openpyxl`を使う場合、二重ループで座標を指定しながら毎回セルを読み直すと耐えがたいほど(n分オーダー)遅くなります。
[`iter_rows`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html?highlight=iter_rows#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.iter_rows)などを使ってシートをまとめて読み込み、イテレータに対して処理をすることで劇的に速くなります。(コンマ秒～)

```
import openpyxl
import time

start = time.time() # 時間計測

fname = r"hoge.xlsx"
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(fname, read_only=True)
ws = wb[wb.sheetnames[0]]
for row in ws.iter_rows(max_row=100, max_col=100):
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == 'パソコン':
            print(cell.row, cell.column)

print(time.time() - start) # 処理時間表示(手元の環境では0.22秒)
```

参考資料:

- [Accessing many cells](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#accessing-many-cells)
- [【Python】Excelのデータをすべて取得する方法](https://pg-chain.com/python-excel-data)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。試してみたのですが，体感的にも早くなったように感じました。また参考資料もありがとうございます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。解決されたようで何よりです。回答に納得していただけましたら[承認](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1736/9820)をお願いいたします。承認された質問は解決済みであることが一目で分かりますので、他の回答者や検索でこの質問にたどり着いた第三者にも質問の状況が分かりやすくなります。過去のご質問もあわせてご対応いただければ幸いです。

Comment: 大変失礼いたしました。承認というシステムがあること自体知りませんでした。ご教示ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

エクセル無い (Google スプレッドシート派とも言う) ので, 速度の確認できないけど
それなり速い かもしれない処理

pandasの `pd.read_excel()` で一括読み取り・検索する方法
(テスト用コードでは CSV読み込み)

```py
import pandas as pd
import io
csvf = io.StringIO('''
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
''')
df = pd.read_csv(csvf, header=None, keep_default_na=False, dtype=str)   # read_excel(dtype=str)
df.loc[2,3] = 'パソコン1'
df.loc[1,1] = 'aパソコン2'

def fn(v):
    r = v.str.contains('パソコン')
    if r.any():
        print(f'row: {v.name}, cols: {list(v.index[r])}')

dmy = df.apply(fn, axis=1)
# row: 1, cols: [1]
# row: 2, cols: [3]
```

NumPyでの文字列検索。`pd.read_excel()` での読み込みまでは同じで, 検索は更に速いはず

```py
import numpy as np

r = np.core.defchararray.find(df.to_numpy().astype('U'), 'パソコン') != -1
np.nonzero(r)
# (array([1, 2]), array([1, 3]))
```

Comment: NumPyでの検索結果は, row (1,2), col (1,3) … という意味

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。確かにpandasでできることが確認できました。勝手にcsvの読み取り専用のライブラリという認識を持っていました。

Comment: 念の為書いておくと, エクセルに書き込みも可能, `engine='openpyxl'` みたいに指定可能で, 指定なくても何れかのエンジンは内部で使われてる。というところ。